# Some question in flux which is produced by magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, gauss-law

I was trying to solving [the problem](http://www.danfleisch.com/maxwell/chapter2/problem1/).

I know that total flux (which produced by magnetic field) of any system is $0$. Even flux in a closed surface is $0$ also. But flux in a non-closed surface isn't always $0$.

$$\phi=\int_S ((5\hat i-3\hat j+4\hat k)\times10^{-9})\cdot(-\hat k)da$$

I have two question about the equation. Why they wrote $\times10^{-9}$? Did they write it cause they were defining only top or bottom of that cylinder.

Is it necessary to assume bottom as negative and top as positive. In simple algebra graph, we assume bottom as negative and top as positive. Can't I assume vice-versa here?

Answer (score 0):

The given expression is for the flux out through the bottom surface where the outward area vector is in the negative (z) direction.  The $10^{-9}$ indicates a field in nano-teslas (which was not given in the problem).  The  flux out through the top will be positive, through the bottom negative, and you do not need to calculate the sides because, as you noted,  the total flux out through all the surfaces would be zero.